# DHCP ACK requests from unknown IPv6 adres

Tags: networking, windows-10, routing, dhcp, troubleshooting

A couple of days ago ive set up my own router. Im pretty new to network related topics and discoverd something in the logs.

Everything worked Just fine until i suddenly lost my connection to my modem, at least that's what win10 said.

When i ping my router it timed out, but when i ping from the web GUI its works Just fine. Did a network adapter reset. Would not help.

Checked the IP adres config in Windows and the web GUI and if it was a common issue with Windows and TP-link.  But sadly nothing.

Now when i look up in the logs i get constantly a ACK and request for all my connected devices from a unknown IPv6 adres.

Is this normal behaviour and should i config a ip for my desktop?

All i have to Note is that it started when i had downloaded a torrent file from the raspberry pi website and opened it in qtorrent

Sorry for the script kiddy Trouble.

Kind regards.

Me

Comment: BTW, you can delete your questions.

Comment: Got a message pop up from the page saying that i can't delete it since people have put effort in it, kay then. but thanks for the reminder, ^^

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, it just needed a reboot. sorry for the hassle.